# simplejson error on return HttpResponse in django 1.5 CBV

Tags: django, json, django-views, simplejson

I am quite new to Django, especially CBV's. So, I have a listView with a post method, where I am trying to output a JSON as follows:

```
from django.utils import simplejson

class MyCoolListView(ListView):
   # template declaration and other stuff

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       # do some stuff
       return context

    def get_queryset(self):
       # do some stuff
       return queryset 

    def post( self, request, *args, **kwargs ):
       # check if user is authenticated and return json
       return HttpResponse( simplejson.dump({ "score": blogpost.score }) , content_type='application/json')
```

However, the HttpResponse on POST, I get:

```
TypeError: dump() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong (I have googled this issue quite a bit, but no luck yet) - and I was wondering if anyone had encountered such a situation/error message. Any guidance to solve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`dump`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html#json.dump) is for dumping to a file, you want [`dumps`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html#json.dumps).

Comment: That is awesome.. just wasted a couple of hours on this! thanks again - I have accepted your answer now

Comment: also, you want to use python's json, not simplejson for django 1.5